# Track Why/Why Not a workflow triggered

Tags: workflow, validation, debugging

I have a formula based workflow in place that will automatically check several custom fields and then change the stage.

I'm wondering if there is a way to see why a particular workflow failed to fire. i.e. what criteria didn't evaluate to true.

I have looked in the debug logs, and the only thing it says is that the formula evaluated to True or False. Is there a way to see which aspect of the formula failed? or am I limited to the general 'formula evaluated to true/false'?

Comment: If you turn up the debug level on Workflow to Finest, you should be able to see the values that are being evaluated.  That might help.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that I can't upgrade the level above info. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: You should be able to, using the Developer Console, on the Debug Tab, select "Change Log Levels", for Workflow, I had all of the options.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was trying to change it under Monitoring>Debug Logs I was able to change it in the console. I will give this a shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality in Salesforce - the only way to check this is to analyse requirements

Comment: Well that's disappointing. Thank you for your answer.